# Installing QGIS on Mac OS X?

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

After failing to successfully install QGIS 2.14.2 Essen on my Mac OS X 10.7.5 (Lion) I thought I could try a previous version of QGIS.

What download file should I use from the QGIS "all releases" list?